# Is there a way to set the minimum width of a slimbox popup?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-plugins, slimbox

We have several images in our app, some of which are less than 100 pixels wide.  When this happens, the slimbox caption text and "Close [X]" link get cutoff.  Is there a way to force the slimbox popup to a minimum width?  There is an initialWidth option, but once the image loads it chooses the width of the image.

Comment: Since, you're tagged your question `css`, yes, there's a css property: `min-width`. Set it to `100px`;

Comment: I tried setting the min-width to 600 on `#lbCenter, #lbBottomContainer` but it did not increase the popup width. I'd be happy with a CSS answer to this question though.

Comment: @kirilloid: I had left the px off the width value. After adding it, the solution works. You should post your comment as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: o_O but how? It shouldn't work this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `min-width` css property. It doesn't allow real width to be less than min-width, even if it is set less eexplicitly in style.

It doesn't work in ie6.

Comment: I added the `min-width: 300px;` property to the `#lbCenter, #lbBottomContainer` rule in slimbox2.css and it works. Thanks!